# Angular 9 universal Server side rendering (SSR) error HTMLCanvasElement

Tags: angular, openstreetmap, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-openlayers

```
Error: NotYetImplemented
    at HTMLCanvasElement.Wo4J.exports.nyi (/path/server/main.js:1:3906285)
    at rj.nf (/path/server/main.js:1:1929447)
    at /path/server/main.js:1:1930713
    at Object.ADia (/path/server/main.js:1:2061225)
    at __webpack_require__ (/path/server/main.js:1:295)
    at Object.7PEY (/path/server/main.js:1:1216808)
    at __webpack_require__ (/path/sen3aPro/server/main.js:1:295)
    at Object.d2mR (/path/server/main.js:1:5425768)
    at __webpack_require__ (/path/server/main.js:1:295)
    at Object.ZAI4 (/path/server/main.js:1:3975117)
```

i am geeting this error angular 9 server side rendering
i am using open street map (OSM) and i think **ngx-openlayers** causes this problem cause when i remove it i got no error

I tried to load **AngularOpenlayersModule** module and the component using this module on client side only but no luck

my **SharedModule.ts**:

```
import {NgModule, PLATFORM_ID} from '@angular/core';
import {OsmViewComponent} from './osm-view/osm-view.component';
import {AngularOpenlayersModule} from 'ngx-openlayers';
import {CommonModule, isPlatformBrowser} from '@angular/common';

let osmC = [];
let ol = [];
if (isPlatformBrowser(PLATFORM_ID)) {
  osmC = [OsmViewComponent];
  ol = [AngularOpenlayersModule];
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AngularOpenlayersModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    OsmViewComponent
  ],
exports: [
  OsmViewComponent
],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

my dependencies are :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.3",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^4.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.1",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.15",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "boostrap": "^2.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "easy-pie-chart": "^2.1.7",
    "firebase": "^7.14.4",
    "get-blob-duration": "^1.1.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mdbootstrap": "^4.14.0",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.5.1",
    "ng-uikit-pro-standard": "file:ng-uikit-pro-standard-9.0.0.tgz",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "ng5-slider": "^1.2.4",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.4.2",
    "ngx-openlayers": "^1.0.0-next.15",
    "ol": "^6.3.1",
    "openlayers": "^4.6.5",
    "recordrtc": "^5.5.9",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "screenfull": "^3.3.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "units-converter": "^1.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
```

Comment: Can you share what versions of packages you are using in package.json ?

Comment: Does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55140957/1160794

Comment: @Praym i added dependencies to the post

Comment: @David yes i tested that it removes the error but the map disappear

Comment: It should only disappear server side, but it should be rendered client side

Comment: @David but it disappear in both sides and it gives thit error in console "ERROR Error: "No provider for t!"

Comment: It may not be related. Since you solve the canvas issue, your code can execute further and you get anotehr error

Comment: @David i used this command to replace the canvas statement by null "sed -i 's/document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d")/null/gI' path/server/main.js " so i think that will remove the error but also ol will not create the map cause he don't have canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I indicated with in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55140957/1160794), open layers relies on the `pixelworks` lib, which tries to create a canvas element when the lib is imported (even if you are not actually instantiating an open layers map). This will not work server side and will cause the SSR process to crash

My hack, based on the fact that I did not need to render the map server side, was to modify the `server.js` file (or `main.js` for angular 9+) to remove the offending bit of code

```
sed -i "s/var context = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');/var context = null;/" dist/server.js
```

This will allow code execution to continue server side. The map will be initiated only in the browser, when the client side angular application takes over.

In the component creating the map, you can also check if you are executing the code client or server side to only instantiate the map client side, using `isPlatformbrowser`

Comment: you have right thanks for your support just small modification in cmd to replace all "CANVAS" in main.ts:
`sed -i 's/document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d")/null/gI' dist/myProject`/server/main.js